# Formas normativas de apellidos que llevan un "de"

Tags: historia, méxico, nombres-propios

Tengo entendido, y no sé si está cierto, que "de" antes de un apellido caracterizaba a alguién como miembro de la nobleza (o la esposa de tal). Sin embargo ese "de" no siempre aparece donde yo lo he esperado. Por ejemplo, hay fuentes que tratan de «Pablo Vicente Solá», y también hay unas que lo nombran el mismo hombre como «Pablo Vicente de Solá» (sí era noble). Su colega Agustín Fernández San Vicente frecuentemente se ha denominado «Agustín Fernández de San Vicente», mientras su falta de nobleza (de lo que sé yo) no había cambiado. Nunca vi mencionarse un tal «Agustín de Fernández San Vicente».

Entonces las variaciones ¿son errores, o no tiene nada que ver con la nobleza, o hay otra explicación? ¿Hay una forma más correcta que las demás?

Si es que importa, la época más relevante a mí es la del año 1800 en la Nueva España.

Comment: Que sepa yo, no hay regla fija.  *de* es frecuente con huérfanos porque sus apellidos serían de tipo *de la santísima trinidad* o algo parecido y religioso (si fuese que unas monjas los cuidaran) y casi siempre que un apellido tenga más de una palabra se emplee *de* (un *Juan El Río» suena fatal, pero «Juan del Río» suena bien) pero tal vez en el caso de un San Vicente los dos elementos se contemplan suficientemente unidos que no hace falta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Spanish names with "de"

There are 3 general spelling styles in Spanish surnames which use "de". The first is chiefly associated with *conquistador* names:

1. **"Patronymic de Toponymic"**

   - e.g. *Gonzalo Fernández de Córdoba, Pero López de Ayala, Vasco Núñez de Balboa*
2. **"de" before full surname**

   Note the ambiguity between *de* when it appears before a full surname as a nobility marker:

   1. Nobility marker

      - e.g. *Álvaro de Bazán, Hernando de Soto*
      - *Miguel de Cervantes, Lope de Vega*

   and when it appears as a non-noble toponymic marker common in e.g. eastern Castile, Alava, and western Navarre:

   2. Non-noble Toponymic

      - e.g. *José de Guzmán Benítez, Cristián Andrés de la Fuente Sabarots*
      - *José Manuel de la Rúa, Cunegunda de la Torre*

And as of 1958:

3. **Avoiding ambiguity with forenames**

   - e.g. *Pedro de Miguel Jiménez* (to avoid reading *Miguel* as a middle name)

   > On petition of the interested party, before the person in charge of the registry, the particle *de* shall be placed before the paternal surname that is usually a first name or begins with one...
   >
   > - [*Article 195, Reglamento del Registro Civil*](http://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Privado/rrc.t5.html)

## Capitalisation

Note that though *de* is spelled in lowercase when it occurs in the full name, when referring to a person by only their surname the standard is to capitalise it:

> Si un apellido español comienza por preposición, o por preposición y artículo, estos se escriben con minúscula cuando acompañan al nombre de pila (*Juan de Ávalos, Pedro de la Calle)*; pero si se omite el nombre de pila, la preposición debe escribirse con mayúscula (*señor De Ávalos, De la Calle*).
>
> - [DPD: Mayúsculas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp#4.3) (4.3)

Exceptionally, *Pedro Arias de Ávila* is most often stylised *[Pedro Arias Dávila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Arias_D%C3%A1vila)*.

## Colonial Hispanic America

In the colonial period and 19th century,

1. **"de [X] Patronymic Matronymic"**

   - e.g. *Juana Enriqueta Josefina de los Sagrados Corazones Fernández del Solar*

---

<sup>**Source:** [*Escuela de genealogía; Heráldica y Nobiliaria (1984). Apuntes de nobiliaria y nociones de genealogía y heráldica: Primer curso (2nd ed.)*](http://www.diputaciondelagrandeza.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/2.pdf), Francisco de Cardenas y Allende (pp. 205–213)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Es posible que el origen de tu extrañeza ante un nombre como Pablo Vicente de Solá, con la preposición ante el segundo apellido en vez del primero, se deba a la forma a la que, hasta hace dos siglos, era relativamente común para denotar los apellidos. Pongamos como ejemplo el nombre de Miguel de Cervantes y Saavedra. Aquí las partículas "de" e "y" vendrían a decir algo así como "Miguel, de la familia Cervantes y de la familia Saavedra". Sin embargo, decimos que el Quijote es de "Cervantes", y no de "de Cervantes", lo que deja claro que la preposición "de" no forma parte del apellido, sino que era la forma en que se escribían los nombres antiguamente.

En el caso de tu ejemplo, la preposición "de" sí parece formar parte del apellido. En ese caso da igual que el apellido sea el primero o el segundo: la preposición va con el apellido y así se transmitirá. Según [un artículo](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/11/04/articulo/1478274157_997681.html) del blog *Verne*:

> [...] la razón principal de la preposición en estos apellidos es una mera cuestión toponímica, ya que en principio informaban sobre el lugar de procedencia del individuo que lo llevaba. Podía ser una ciudad o localidad (Vigo - De Vigo) o hacer referencia a algo que distinguía a la villa de la que procedían (Del Río, De la Torre, Del Bosque).

A continuación explica por qué hoy día parece que esa preposición "de" se asocia con la nobleza:

> A partir de el [sic] siglo XIX, comienza a suprimirse la preposición. Esa transición ocurrió de una forma algo caótica, así que algunas familias tradicionales decidieron mantenerla, ya que tuvieron esa posibilidad, explica el profesor. Al conservarse también en apellidos compuestos (Sáenz de Santamaría, Méndez de Vigo), que nos resultan más propios de familias de clase alta, nos encontramos la preposición más a menudo en los apellidos de los que consideramos ricos o cercanos a la aristocracia, aunque su significado original no tuviera relación con la clase social.

Este texto es clave para entender por qué a veces se encuentra el nombre de Pablo Vicente Solá con la preposición y otras no, responde simplemente a ese "caos" mencionado por el cual la preposición se suprimió de forma errática.

Comment: Caos que llega a nuestros días, por lo que hoy podemos encontrar una persona con *de* en el apellido, pero su hermano o hermana no lo lleva. En España tenemos a las exministras Ana Palacio y Loyola de Palacio, por ejemplo.

Comment: Quizás hay que entender el vasco para saber esto: no sé si Solá sea demónimo. El segundo apellido del señor fue Arrizabalaga (de lo que veo, él no solía usarlo). Esta genealogía sugiere que la gran familia no ocupaba el "de": https://sites.google.com/site/leinztarra/sola

Comment: Discúlpeme por no incluir aquellos detalles al principio; no los ví tan importantes en el momento. Parece posible que el sitio "leinztarra" haya quitado cualquier "de" en todas las familias, ya que no veo ninguno.

Comment: En el caso de Cristina Fernández de Kirchner, por ejemplo ¿Es normal en el mundo hispanohablante formar un apellido así con el nombre del esposo o es específico a la Argentina?

Comment: @aris - Si no se ha preguntado todavía, yo pienso que esa pregunta valdría la pena poner, aparte.  Se puede usar la etiqueta "diferencias regionales".