# When to include "de" in short formal name?

Tags: nombres-propios

It seems that the short formal way to refer to "[Hernando de Soto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hernando_de_Soto)" is "de Soto", but that for "[Francisco de Vitoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Vitoria)" is "Vitoria".

Why is "de" included in the former but dropped in the latter? Are there any general rules that determine this?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that "Vitoria" is a toponym, while "Soto" is not (at least by itself). Could you check [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30411/12637) to see if its answers shed some light on yours?

Comment: I would always include the de, myself.

Answer (score 1):

We usual use the whole last name as the formal way to go. This specific case (Francisco de Vitoria) is a weird example, I would never have called him 'Vitoria' but 'de Vitoria', being a native speaker myself. This is probably influenced by old Spanish uses, but that's not the rule nowadays. Just use the whole last name when speaking formally.